# Laravel problema con directivas de Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Estoy usando Laravel 5.7. En `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` he creado, en el método `boot()`, una directiva Blade, así:

```
Blade::directive('level', function ($string, $nivel) {
    $string .= "(".$nivel.")";
    return "<?php echo $string; ?>";
});
```

Por supuesto, al principio, he importado correctamente el facade Blade, así:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
```

Desde una vista, intento llamar a la directiva, así:

```
@level("Nombre", 2)
```

Como véis, la llamo con dos argumentos, separados por comas. En la firma de la closure de la directiva hay dos parámetros, separados por coma, por lo que, en principio, todo parece correcto. Sin embargo, cuando intento cargar la vista, la respuesta es:

> Too few arguments to function App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::App\Providers{closure}(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Es decir, parece como si estuviera esperando los dos argumentos (lo que se supone que debe ser), pero sólo recibiera uno.

Sé que, para lo que hace la directiva, no es necesaria, que se podría hacer directamente en la vista. Pero esa no es la cuestión. El caso es que voy a necesitar ampliar el código de la directiva, y voy a necesitar que esté disponible desde varias vistas, así que la cuestión es saber por qué no reconoce los dos argumentos.

Comment: Tal vez te sirva... [Pass multiple parameters to a blade directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003733/pass-multiple-parameters-to-a-blade-directive). Saludos!

Comment: ¿Intentas llamar una función con esa directiva?

Comment: Hola. He probado lo del enlace de Fran Islas, pero no me funciona. Dentro de la directiva no llamo a ninguna otra función. La única función es la propia closure de la directiva. El caso es que si monto la directiva para funcionar con un solo argumento, funciona perfectamente. Incluso la paso como argumento una variable que me llega del controlador y me la lee. Sin embargo, en el momento que intento pasar dos argumentos, me da el error de que sólo recibe uno. En la docu sólo hay un ejemplo con un sólo argumento, y en Internet no encuentro nada. Os ha pasado alguna vez?. Darme una pista.

Comment: Es correcto que solo permite un argumento, pero hay una solución, en unas horas te la pongo.